# Unable to insert an array of nested javascript objects into mongodb using mongoose models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
osVersionsSchema.collection.insertMany(osVersionRelatedData, function onInsertion(error, insertedDocs) {
  if (error) {
    error.status = 500;
    callback(error, null)
    console.log("Insertion Failure");
  } else {
    console.log("Insert Success");
    callback(error, insertedDocs);
    console.log(insertedDocs);
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you please correctly format your code (4 spaces in front, take a look at the editor help) and express your question like *I try this, expect that but got something like..*

Comment: Thanks Flob, i am able to insert data when I am not using exports.create, but when I use exports.create and in that if i try giving an array of data for example the osVersionRelated Data, It is not happening so.. Please help

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly to allow anyone trying to help you to reproduce the problem

Comment: i have an array , i need to insert that into a mongodb using mongoose model. I have created a schema and i try to insert data into that model. When I keep my array and model.collection.insertMany(array, function inserted(error, insertedDocs) ) inside the block of exports.create =function(data, callback) i am unable to insert data into the mongodb , but when I place that Model.collection.insertMany outside the exports.create block  I am able to insert data into mongodb

Comment: Can any one help me out please

Comment: If you would edit your question to contain all the necessary information anyone able to help you would find it a lot easier to understand your problem. I haven't use mongoose for some time and can't help you with your problem, just tried to help you making your question easier to understand.